# How can I use substring-before in Xpath to remove a suffix that is being scraped from a website?

Tags: xml, xpath, lxml

I am trying to scrape a product name from a website (https://www.dvdwholesale.co.uk/dvds/) using Xpath to point to the product name. The path itself works but the problem is they have appended their product names with 'Wholesale UK' which is throwing out my data. I need to filter it out somehow.

I had a look at `substring-before` which I think could maybe resolve the issue but have been unsuccessful in working it out myself. It is causing issues as the product name needs to be cross referenced with other sites for arbitrage purposes.

Sorry if this is formatted incorrectly or anything I am learning on the go here.

The Xpath I used to extract the product name was `//h2[contains(@class, 'woocommerce-loop-product__title')]/text()`. Everything I tried using `substring-before` just came back as invalid syntax, I'm not even sure this is the right way to go about it but I couldn't make it work regardless. The product name needs to be cross referenced with other sites for arbitrage purposes and the appendage throws out matches on the lookup.

Edit: Found a solution `substring-before(//h2[contains(@class, 'woocommerce-loop-product__title')]/text(), ' Wholesale UK')` however this only selects one product, does anyone know how I can amend this path so that every product card on the page is selected (40 results)?

Comment: Most methods on XPath 1.0 will operate on the first node of a node set.

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0 which lxml supports can't do that in one expression but with Python it is easy to use list comprehension and a Python function to extract the function from the result of using the XPath `/h2[contains(@class, 'woocommerce-loop-product__title')]/text()` e.g. `[s[:s.index(" Wholesale UK")] for s in root.xpath("//h2[contains(@class, 'woocommerce-loop-product__title')]/text()")]`.

Of course that same list comprehension can be applied to do your two needed XPath evaluations:

```
result = [h2.xpath('substring-before(., " Wholesale UK")') for h2 in root.xpath("//h2[contains(@class, 'woocommerce-loop-product__title')]")]
```